# Browsers Power Consumption

Tags: web-browser

Why do the Browsers like Firefox and Chrome on OSX consume more and more power over time.

If reset and reopen same pages they power consumption is way less, but again it will grow over time.

My question is why the power consumption goes up over time, and it is back down after restarting browser while opening same pages ?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely not the Browser's fault. I guess you're on some badly implemented (bloated) pages that are packed with tons of JavaScript.

1. Try disabling JavaScript and compare to the full-featured version.
2. Also AdBlocking or plugins such as uMatrix ([Chrome Add On](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en), [FireFox Add On](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/)) allow you to selectively disable features (frames, js, media) for certain vendors. Maybe you get an idea what may be going on in modern websites :)
3. Have a look at your Browser's Development tools. Chrome for example has some very nice features hidden behind the `Performance` tab. It shows you what happens on your page (rendering, parsing, cpu/gpu usage)

But this is quite a broad field you're about to enter here. Maybe have a read on web performance before you start digging into the tips above.

Comment: while correct, not quite the answer I as looking for. The question is why overtime the Power consumption goes up, and it is reduced after restarting the browser and reopening same pages.

Comment: Chrome has a task manager included (More Tools > Task Manager). Maybe identify if it is the browser itself or a certain tab causing this. Then proceed with the stuff above -> Dev tools.